# How to put a string from an input field and put it into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am very new to programing so sorry if this question is to vague.

I have a simple  html input field: 
input class="draft" type="text"

and I have a javascript function (the function only accepts strings):
Message.send()

Using javascript/jQuery how do I take the string the user typed into the input field and place it into the Message.send() function (in string form)?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: use the `value` property in pure JS or `val()` method in jQuery.

Comment: Firstly: Welcome to StackOverflow. Secondly: Try searching for your answer prior to posting a question. Questions with simple answers like this one can often be found very easily.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
Message.send($("input.draft").val());
```

javascript:

```
Message.send(document.querySelector("input.draft").value);
```

Comment: It is better to flag as duplicate then provide an answer.

Comment: First off thank you very much Elvis D'Souza for the answer it did exactly what I needed it to! Secondly Matt Green I spent that evening searching google and stack overflow without finding an answer (or at least one I could understand). What would I search for to find an answer to this question? Im not trying to be smart just trying to learn so next time I can figure it out myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery needed. I'm not sure what you mean by `place it into the Message.send() function (in string form)`, so I assume you get the value in the text input and use it as an argument in the `Message.send()` function.

Try this:

```
Message.send(document.getElementsByClassName("draft")[0].value);
```

Comment: It is better to flag as duplicate then provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input field is something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="someInputField" name="someInputField" class="inputFields" />
```

You could do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //We use the field's id to refer to it and get to its value (the text in it):
   var message = $('#someInputField').val();
   //And then you might call the function like:
   nameOfTheFuntion(message);
</script>
```

You would need to have jQuery libraries to make it work though, but you could do without them by replacing:

```
$('#someInputField').val();
```

with

```
document.getElementById('someInputField').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<input>` box an `id` for example

```
<input type="text" id="blah" />
```

In your `javascript` you are able to reference the `<input>` like so:

```
var strBlah = document.getElementById("blah").value;
```

Now you have the value typed into the `<input>` box so  you would do the following:

```
Message.send(strBlah)
```